# How to omit default values of middle parameters when calling a function?

Tags: php, default-value, optional-parameters

I have function:

```
function abc( $name, $city = 'duhok', $age = 30 ){

    echo $name.", ".$city.", ".$age;

}

abc( 'Dilovan', null, 26 ); // output: Dilovan, , 26
```

And I want to output will:`Dilovan, duhok, 26`

I want way to use this function without set second argument and the second argument write default value.

```
abc( 'Dilovan', [what i use here to write defualt value ?], 26 );
```

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of that question. This question asks how to apply *the* default value, given in the parameter list. In this case that would be 'duhok'. (The solution may be the same, but I don't think the question is.)

Comment: @user2864740 , ok. short answer would be: it's not possible.

Comment: There was proposition: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/skipparams

Comment: Thanks for answers, @sectus I want way it standard off PHP library.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: that's not possible without writing some code.

#### Solution 1

Add this logic to your function body instead of the declaration; for instance:

```
function abc($name, $city = null, $age = 30)
{
    $city = $city !== null ? $city : 'duhok';
    // rest of your code
}
```

Then you can call the function like so:

```
abc('Dilovan', null, 29);
```

This will assign the default value if the given `$city` is `null`.

#### Solution 2

You can use [Reflection](http://php.net/reflection) to find out what the default value of a parameter is:

```
$rf = new ReflectionFunction('abc');
$params = $rf->getParameters();

$default_city = $params[1]->getDefaultValue();

abc('Dilovan', $default_city, 26);
```

Comment: OK that is mean not possible, thanks a lot.

Comment: Mmmm, why that is not possible in PHP ???

Comment: @user3928495 That's how default values are implemented in most languages; it's meant to yield its default value *only* if not passed at all. This is also why the optional parameters are always found at the back of the declaration.

Comment: @user3928495 I've updated my answer to show how one could obtain the default value from any function.

Comment: I will try to use Reflection, Its best idea for this
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score -1):

pass `null`:

```
abc( 'Dilovan',null, 26 );
```

Comment: When I pass null will not print anything

Answer (score -1):

**Test [Here](https://eval.in/178026)**

```
function abc( $name, $city = null, $age = 30 )
{
    if( $city == null )
    {
        $city = 'duhok';
    }

   echo $name.", ".$city.", ".$age;
}


abc( 'Dilovan', null, 26 );
```

Comment: Mark as correct answer please if this code heled you

Comment: It's not considered polite to coax users into accepting your answer without having had some interaction first.

Comment: Yes, I know this way, but I want to pass thing to print default value of argument

It is possible ??

Comment: In my opinion you cannot do this in diferent way

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
function abc( $name, $city = 'duhok', $age = 30 )
{
    if($city == null || $city == NULL)
    {
        $city = 'duhok'
    }

   echo $name.", ".$city.", ".$age;
}
```

Comment: I know this way, but I want to pass thing to print default value of argument